# How to prevent drupalSettings to sort settings object

Tags: 8, javascript

I attach `drupalSettings` in a preprocess hook using code similar to the following one.

```
$settings = [
  'bcd' => 'BCD',
  'abc' => 'ABC'
];

$variables['#attached']['drupalSettings']['options'] = $settings;
```

When I print the content of `drupalSettings` using `console.log(drupalSettings.options);` I  get a sorted object.

```
{ 'abc' : 'ABC','abc' : 'BCD'}
```

Is this the normal behavior? How can I prevent it?

Comment: I don't check code, but i have a tip for you. Using json encode on php convert to string and using json parse on js to convert to object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not Drupal that sorts the *drupalSettings* array, but it's `console.log()` that sorts the properties of `drupalSettings.options` before outputting it. See [Show original order of object properties in console.log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39054764/show-original-order-of-object-properties-in-console-log) where the answer explains this.

If you really want to avoid `console.log()` sorts the object properties, you could call `console.log()` using code similar to the following one.

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj, drupalSettings.options, null, 2));
```

I would rather use this code if it's really important to see the object properties in the order they are set.

Comment: Thanks @Kiamlaluno it's right, not  Drupal that sort the drupalSettings.